# IF, OR, and CONCATENATE Statement with nest IFs

Tags: 2013

I have a list of consultant types on SP2013 - various kinds of domestic consultants (labeled as marketing, strategy, etc.) and only one label for international consultants. The consultants are reviewed on a quarterly basis but domestic ones are reviewed three months in advance of their contract end date and international ones are reviewed six months in advance of their end date. I have written code for a calculated column that works if I want to find the review date for domestics, or if I want to find the review date for internationals, but not if I combine it.

Here's the code I have so far for domestic types (and our quarters a slightly shifted, hence the January code subtracting a year):

```
=IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=2,[Contract End Month]=3,[Contract End Month]=4),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 1Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=5,[Contract End Month]=6,[Contract End Month]=7),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 2Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=8,[Contract End Month]=9,[Contract End Month]=10),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 3Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=11,[Contract End Month]=12),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 4Q"),

IF([Contract End Month]=1,CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]-1," 4Q")))))))

And here's the code for Internationals:

=IF([Consultant Type]="International",

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=2,[Contract End Month]=3,[Contract End Month]=4),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]-1," 4Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=5,[Contract End Month]=6,[Contract End Month]=7),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 1Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=8,[Contract End Month]=9,[Contract End Month]=10),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 2Q"),

IF(OR([Contract End Month]=11,[Contract End Month]=12,[Contract End Month]=1),CONCATENATE([Contract End Year]," 3Q"))))))
```

I want to combine these two so that regardless of the consultant type the column will calculate the correct review date, which would be the quarter and contract end year. Every time I try to combine these as "OR" statements I get an error or the International portion of the code returns "No" instead of a value.

I'm done beating my head against a wall, I'm asking the experts. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

DISCLOSURE: Not tested in SharePoint, works in Excel; made sure to use SP friendly formulas.

To simplify it down, you could minimize repeating fields, and use CHOOSE.

Full code sample:

```
'=IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",
[Contract End Year]-IF([Contract End Month]=1,1,0)&" "&CHOOSE[Contract End Month],4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
[Contract End Year]-IF(AND(2<=[Contract End Month],[Contract End Month]<=4),1,0)&" "&CHOOSE([Contract End Month],3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
)&"Q"
```

**Breakdown:** 

- *within each step, added code is in **bold***

1: Combine the [Consultant Type] IF-THEN.


**```
 =IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",
{NOT-INTERNATIONAL-STUFF-PLACEHOLDER},
{IS-INTERNATIONAL-STUFF-PLACEHOLDER})
```**

 
2: Extract and concatenate the "Q" since it appears in all cases.

```
=IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",
{NOT-INTERNATIONAL-STUFF-PLACEHOLDER},
{IS-INTERNATIONAL-STUFF-PLACEHOLDER})
&"Q"
```

3: Handle year instance.

• Subtract 1 from year, if NOT International and Month = 1; else 0 (keep as same).
• Subtract 1 from year, if IS International and Month is between 2 and 5; else 0 (keep as same).

```
=IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",
[Contract End Year]-IF([Contract End Month]=1,1,0),
[Contract End Year]-IF(AND(2<=[Contract End Month],[Contract End Month]<=4),1,0))
&"Q"
```

4: Now handle month.

• Instead of nested IFs you could use CHOOSE.
• Due to the wrapback nature of this Quarter selection, actual Quarter of month doesn't apply.

```
'=IF([Consultant Type]<>"International",
[Contract End Year]-IF([Contract End Month]=1,1,0)&" "&CHOOSE[Contract End Month],4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
[Contract End Year]-IF(AND(2<=[Contract End Month],[Contract End Month]<=4),1,0)&" "&CHOOSE([Contract End Month],3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
)&"Q"
```

RESULTS:
When 2018-01  International shows ► (2018 3Q) | Local shows ► (2017 4Q)
When 2018-02  International shows ► (2017 4Q) | Local shows ► (2017 1Q)
When 2018-03  International shows ► (2017 4Q) | Local shows ► (2017 1Q)
When 2018-04  International shows ► (2017 4Q) | Local shows ► (2017 1Q)
When 2018-05  International shows ► (2018 1Q) | Local shows ► (2017 2Q)
When 2018-06  International shows ► (2018 1Q) | Local shows ► (2017 2Q)
When 2018-07  International shows ► (2018 1Q) | Local shows ► (2017 2Q)
When 2018-08  International shows ► (2018 2Q) | Local shows ► (2017 3Q)
When 2018-09  International shows ► (2018 2Q) | Local shows ► (2017 3Q)
When 2018-10  International shows ► (2018 2Q) | Local shows ► (2017 3Q)
When 2018-11  International shows ► (2018 3Q) | Local shows ► (2017 4Q)
When 2018-12  International shows ► (2018 3Q) | Local shows ► (2017 4Q)